# Revealing structure of clusters in a dataset

Tags: clustering, histogram

I have obtained values for the same parameter in various locations and I want to cluster them (abundance fraction of different minerals in a hyper-spectral image). These fractions have spatial correlations, for example, an abundance of one mineral could be increased as of the other is decreased.

However, a dendrogram does not give an appropriate clustering structure. In fact, fractions are derived from unknown distributions and they are in unequal sizes for each mineral. Each of them has its own histograms and all of them are 1-dimensional (25 dataset or mineral).

Question: how can I reveal the structure of clusters in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to consider both *frequentist* and *Bayesian* approaches, assessing their applicability to your particular circumstances. For the former, take a look at *mixture model-based clustering* (see [basic information](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat557/node/99) and [recommended R package](http://www.stat.washington.edu/mclust) `mclust`). For the latter, take a look at [Dirichlet mixture models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#Use_in_Dirichlet_mixture_models) and, possibly, *Dirichlet diffusion trees*, which apply hierarchical clustering to Dirichlet process mixtures: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~radford/ftp/dft-val7.pdf. Some other related literature can be found via relevant links at Radford Neal's [research interests page](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~radford/research.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to spend a lot more time to preprocess your data.

Hellinger's work (1909) indicated that for histogram data, taking the square root of values can yield good results if you are using Euclidean distances (c.f. Hellinger kernel).

Make sure to not blindly mix values from different scales, or the one value with the largest scale will dominate your result.

Experiment with ignoring features altogether.